# Finding sum of digits of a three digit natural number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The digits $x, y, z$ of the three-digit natural number xyz satisfy the equation $169x$+ $13y$+$z$= $786$. What is the sum of the digits of the three digit natural number xyz?

Why x y and z can only be 4,8 and 6 and not 5,7,6 or any other combination of number. Or why sum of digits can't be 15? Why is it 18?

Comment: Do you mean $(xyz)_{13}$ ... ecks,why, zed base $13$ ?

Comment: I did not understand what you are saying @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: The digits of the number $768$ are seven, six & eight base $10$. But we do have $(768)_{10}=(486)_{13}$ ... you want the sum of the digits ? ... in what base ?

Comment: In base 10. @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: The sum of the digits of $(768)_{10}$ are $7+6+8$ (base 10). So I am baffled as to why you appear to be converting it to base $13$.

Comment: I think, that there is some point missing. $xyz$ is a number in base 10 satisfying $xyz_{13}=786_{10}$. We want the sum of digits $xyz_{10}$.

Answer (score 2):

$169x+ 13 y + z = 786$ is decimal representation of number $xyz$ in base $13$, so to compute $x,y$ and $z$ we have to follow the procedure:

- $x = \left\lfloor \frac{786}{13^2} \right\rfloor = 4$
- $y = \left\lfloor \frac{786 - 13^2 x}{13^1} \right\rfloor = 8$
- $z = \left\lfloor \frac{786 - 13^2 x-13y}{13^0} \right\rfloor = 6$

Comment: How can you write $x=786/13^2$, I understand you are telling me that it is base 13. But then how can we divide it by base to get values of x y and z @JaroslawMatlak

Comment: The procedure is the same, as when we want to get number representation in any other base.

Comment: I am not understanding it. @JaroslawMatlak